# Image becoming transparent when placed within view

Tags: react-native

My app has a background image which has a slightly transparent view placed over it to provide a blue tint to the background image. I am now trying to place the app logo on top of these views but when I do so the logo appears to take on the opacity of the view providing the tint.

I am very new to react native but what I basically need is to have: background image > view > logo.

To demonstrate what I mean, the app logo should look like this:

[image: What the app logo should look like]

But it currently looks washed out, like this:

[image: How the logo currently looks]

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import Logo from './Logo';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require('./images/city.png')}
                    style={styles.backgroundStyle}
                >
                    <View style={styles.backgroundOverlayStyle}>
                        <Logo />
                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    backgroundStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    },
    backgroundOverlayStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#003284',
        opacity: 0.5
    }

};

export default App;
```

Logo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

const Logo = () => {
    const { logoStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={logoStyle} source={require('./images/request-first-logo-white.png')} />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    container: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        opacity: 1,
    }, 

    logoStyle: {
        width: '70%',
        height: '65%',
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        //backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }
};

export default Logo;
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Check the code @ https://codesandbox.io/embed/zr3j1wxml, see if this is what you want

Comment: @Kranthi Thanks that worked.

Answer (score 0):

you need you define blurRadius for ImageBackground

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { View, Text, ImageBackground,Image } from 'react-native';

 const Logo = () => {
 const { logoStyle } = styles;
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image  style={logoStyle} source={{uri:'https://www.what-dog.net/Images/faces2/scroll001.jpg'}} />
    </View>
);
};

export default class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
            <ImageBackground
                source={{uri : 'https://pngstocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/cb-background-10.jpeg'}}
                style={styles.backgroundStyle}
                blurRadius={30}
            >
                    <Logo />
            </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
    backgroundStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
},
backgroundOverlayStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#003284',
},
container: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
 }, 

logoStyle: {
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  resizeMode: 'contain',
  //backgroundColor: 'blue'
 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this just blurs the background though and the logo is still washed out.

Comment: remove this view <View style={styles.backgroundOverlayStyle}>